# Names with accented characters are not displayed correctly on a company page

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Example here: https://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/particular-software

The name should be Andreas Öhlund

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for reporting this. We recently tightened up the security around some of our HTML rendering code and tried to catch all of the double-encodings before we made those changes live. Obviously we missed some! We'll get a fix for this out soon.